# Embedded pages by ID are not respecting Private and Draft status

Tags: php

Have an issue where I have a series of pages loaded into a websites index using code shown bellow:

```
<?php $id = 1767; $p = get_page($id); echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content); ?>
```

But the information from these pages are not respecting Private and Draft status. Normally this is fine with me. But a couple of them are either to me scheduled updates. But no matter what the pages status is it's visible to an unlogged in reader of the page in all browsers I've tried.

I have done some reading about the `page_status` code but I'm too much of a layman to work out how to get it to work.

Help and advice most welcome.
Thanks

Ok thanks Piyush Rawat. I implemented the follow. Works correctly as far as I can tell.

```
<?php $id = 2841; $p = get_page($id);  if ( get_post_status ( $id ) == 'publish' ) { echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content); } ?>
```

Comment: you can get the status of the page with $p->post_status. Then you can use conditional tags as per your requirements

Comment: Thank you so much. Added my implementation to the original post.

Comment: if you solved it, please make an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the get_page() to get the current status and do something based on its output.

```
 $id = YOUR_ID; 
 $p = get_page($id);
 $status = $p->post_status;

 if($status == 'publish'){
      //Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to hardcode Page ID's into a site, that will bite you later on.

You can use [get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) function to retrieve pages. It will automaticallyby default only query post status 'publish'. If really needed you can give a bunch of page ID's there using the include parameter.